# GET request with thousands of parameters

Tags: json-api

I am building some JSON API endpoints which could take potentially thousands of query string parameters.  Something which concerns me is the artificial limits set per browser, highlighted in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/812962/1001408

I know I could convert my GET endpoints to POST endpoints, but this is breaking the JSON API specification as far as I can tell.  Has anyone else had to work around this restriction?

Comment: Switching to POST is probably the workaround which you will find when this problem comes up.  Would doing that actually break something, or would it rather just sit unwell with you as being bad design?

Comment: It sits badly with me because the spec specifically mentions GET and not POST.  Plus also, it's technically still a a GET disguised as a POST.  Nothing would break, it just doesn't _feel_ right

Comment: No, it doesn't feel right at all, but then again maybe those servers and browsers should not have put such size limits on GET requests.  No specification is perfect.